# How to fix memory issue when reading parquet into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I am reading files from S3 into a Pandas data frame: the files are parquets that have been partitioned. I will be using this inside Lambda so I need to be very conservative with memory. When I run the following statement, I run out of memory:

```
pq.ParquetDataset(f's3://{path}', filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

However if I run the following, I am fine:

```
pq.ParquetDataset(f's3://{path}', filesystem=s3)
```

Then it breaks again if add:

```
pq.ParquetDataset(f's3://{path}', filesystem=s3).read_pandas()
```

The uncompressed data size is 500 MB, and I have 3 GB of RAM. Is there a more memory efficient way to pull a series of parquets into a Pandas Dataframe?

**Something else I tried:**

This did not work because it breaks if it contains strings that are too long:

```
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=f'{prefix}'):
    obj = s3_resource.Object(buckey,obj.key)
    obj.download_fileobj(buffer)
    df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)
```

**Another try that doesnt work:**

```
def memory_optimized_pull(datekey, filter_column, filter_column_value):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket_name = 'bn'
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(name=bucket_name)
    df_list = []
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=...):
        f = s3.open(f'{bucket_name}/{obj.key}')
        df = pq.read_table(f).to_pandas()
        df = df[df[filter_column] == filter_column_value]
        df_list.append(df)
    return pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Comment: What version pyarrow is installed.  You might be running into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6060 which affect 0.14.0 and 0.14.1.  You can try using 0.13.0, a build off of master or wait for 0.15.0 to be released (there will hopefully be a release candidate out this week).

Answer (score 0):

The reason `pq.ParquetDataset(f's3://{path}', filesystem=s3)` doesn't run out of memory is that it hasn't loaded anything. It just encapsulates the details of how to read the dataset, but doesn't actually do anything until calling read.

When you say that the uncompressed data size is 500 MB, do you mean once loaded in memory? If that's the file size from s3, it's probably compressed using snappy (default with pandas `to_parquet`).

In general, parquet is meant for larger datasets and AWS Lambdas aren't the best choice for heavier ETL jobs.

Comment: No that is uncompressed file size loaded into memory which I found by loading it into a pandas DataFrame and checking the size in Sagemaker with `.info(memory_usage='deep')`

Comment: The data is immediately filtered down to about 5000 records after this step. This is not a heavy ETL job.

Comment: Is each file in the partitioned dataset is 500mb or that's the total? If it's really just 500mb, why not just use a single file? I'm also not sure how it's applicable that it will be filtered down to 5000 records **_after_** this step

Comment: All data in total is 500 MB. While I agree with you, I am not responsible to this partitioning.

Comment: I would perform the same operations that you're trying to do in the lambda from within the Sagemaker notebook and inspect them with a memory profiler. Here's a some examples of that: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.07-timing-and-profiling.html

Comment: Ok I will try that. I added another method I am working on to filter the files independently, but it is still running out of memory.

Comment: It appears that it takes about 2 GB of memory to unpack a dataframe in memory of about 50 MB.